# how to do tooltip on button in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I am having download icon on my page i want that when the user takes his finger over the button a tooltip should show as showing download in text.

is there any option in iphone to show a tooltip???

Answer (score 3):

Dan is absolutely right on how to do it but I'd answer you should rethink your design to not need the tooltip at all.

There's a reason that there isn't one by default - what if the user presses down on the button to see what it does, reads the tooltip and realises that's not what they want. They then have to be very careful not to let go while still over the button or it will press and do the wrong thing. (And most users don't know that they can press down over a button, move their finger off it and release it to cancel the press.)

You should rethink your design to make it obvious what the buttons do without the user having to interact with them first.

However, if you definitely still want a tooltip, Dan's method is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing built-in, no. If you think about it, generally a tooltip appears when you mouse over the target item. There's no "mousing over" with a touch interface.

You can definitely roll your own, though. Start by placing a view containing your tooltip contents exactly where you want it with an alpha of 0%. Make a custom button with no content that outlines your download icon, and hook its "touch down inside" action to a method that animates the tooltip view to an alpha of 100%. Hook your button's "touch up inside" , "touch down outside" and "touch up outside" actions (and maybe some others--you might want to experiment with that) to a method that animates the tooltip view back to an alpha of 0%.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't native support for this in iOS. But you can create your own.

I ended up creating my custom tooltip/popover class.

Can be initalised with any content view and dynamically adjusts it's frame.

Hope it helps.

https://github.com/akeara/AKETooltip